# SwiftUI - Update body only once when @EnviromentObject and @State changes

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

I have created this example project replicating my app architecture, in which a random number is generated in a `Manager` class and then displayed in the `SecondaryView`. Inside this view, calculations need to be made based on this `randomNumber` and displayed as well (`randomNumberTimesTen`). This example is of course non-sensical and could be fixed by changing the architecture. The important part is the relation between `@State` and `@EnvironmentObject` and they need to stay where they are.

How can I make sure that the body of `SecondaryView` is only updated once after the `randomNumberTimesTen` has been calculated and not twice? At the moment it happens right away after the `randomNumber` was generated and this causes issues in my app as I need the value of `randomNumberTimesTen` before the body can be drawn correctly.

I think the problematic part might be the `.onChange(of: manager.randomNumber)` as this is probably only executed when the body is updated. Is there a way to move this somewhere else? The `multiplyByTen()` needs to stay in the `SecondaryView` though.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var manager = Manager()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SecondaryView()
                .environmentObject(manager)
            Button("Random Number") {
                manager.generateRandomNumber()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondaryView: View {
    @State var randomNumberTimesTen: Int = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var manager: Manager

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Random Number: \(manager.randomNumber)")
            Text("Random Number x10: \(randomNumberTimesTen)")
        }
        .onChange(of: manager.randomNumber) { _ in
            multiplyByTen()
        }
    }

    func multiplyByTen() {
        randomNumberTimesTen = manager.randomNumber * 10
    }
}


public class Manager: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var randomNumber: Int = 0

    public func generateRandomNumber() {
        self.randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0..<10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two "source of truth" changed, so two updates. So make one - `manager.randomNumber` as it is really so, and everything else should be just based on it.

This exact case can be fixed by making `randomNumberTimesTen` calculable instead of state, like

```
struct SecondaryView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var manager: Manager

    private var randomNumberTimesTen: Int {
        self.manager.randomNumber * 10
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Random Number: \(manager.randomNumber)")
            Text("Random Number x10: \(randomNumberTimesTen)")
        }
    }
}
```